# dpkg error grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: linux, grub, uefi, dpkg, vmware

I am currently facing a perplexing issue while attempting to install DragonOS on VMWare, and despite several efforts, I have been unable to resolve the error outlined below.

I have performed a fresh install multiple times, reinstalled the VM, and even downloaded the most recent ISO to ensure I am working with the latest version. However, regardless of these actions, the error persists when attempting an upgrade. It's worth noting that this issue only occurs within the VM, and the copy of DragonOS on my laptop remains unaffected.

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree... 
Done Reading state information... 
Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.187.6+2.06-2ubuntu14.4) ... mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: 
special device /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VBdb08de81-62dba820-part2 does not exist. 
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure): 
installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 32
Errors were encountered while processing:grub-efi-amd64-signed 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit: Added requested `ls -al /dev/disk/by-id/`

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Dec 21 06:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 160 Dec 21 06:35 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Dec 21 06:35 ata-VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive_10000000000000000001 -> ../../sr0
```

edit 2

It seems that:

`special device /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VBdb08de81-62dba820-part2`

is missing so how would I create the special device? i'm still learning Linux and really appreciate the help as this is above my knowledge right now.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -al  /dev/disk/by-id/`.

Comment: edit: updated 28 December to reflect information requested by @GAD3R and an observation as to why I think may be the issue I just don't know what to do about it or where to look.